# Python in windows : programming from the command line

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I want to to write simple multi line programs in python from the cmd, what I want to do is to pass an argument then do some manipulations and save output to text file, I found some examples online but nothing is working for me.
for example here is somthing that I want to do:
`>echo "230-20-5" | python -c "[commands]" > output.txt`
I want to split it, take each number and add 5 to each one then sum the results so the output.txt should be:
`235
25
10
the result is : 270`

By the way, If someone can give me a tutorial online that would be great
thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not write an actual Python script, or use the tools the command line already provides?

Comment: because it would be great to use pipe with windows commands :)

Comment: I suppose you can always run python script from command line!

Comment: yeah but it wouldn't be the same , this method will make you save time

Comment: are you asking what has to go in "[commands]" or how you do i/o redirection in windows?

Comment: Yes,I am asking what has to go in [commands], I know how to do simple one line commands like `>python -c "print 'Hello' " > output.txt ` but not multiple lines commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes,I am asking what has to go in [commands], I know how to do simple one line commands like >python -c "print 'Hello' " > output.txt but not multiple lines commands

No idea why you want to do this, but here you go:

```
>> echo "230-20-5" | python2.7 -c "exec(\"inp=raw_input()\nlst=[int(x)+5 for x in inp.split('-')]\nfor x in lst: print x\nprint \'the result is:\', sum(lst)\")" > out
```

`out` will contain:

```
235
25
10
the result is: 270
```

I tested this with bash, so you might need minor adjustments for whatever shell you are using under windows.

Comment: didn't work for me  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    \"230-20-5\"
                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: @user2776193 yeah that's probably because you have to escape " and ' differently in your shell. The general approach however is to use `exec("command1\ncommand2")`, splitting commands with `\n`.

Comment: Ok so to make it work on windows, you have only to remove the escape charter from the echo like this `echo "230-20-5" | ....`

Comment: Now that I can use python from command line , I won't miss anymore bash commands line sed,grep and awk etc etc .  :)

Answer (score -1):

Put the following code in a file say foo_bar.py

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("val")
args = parser.parse_args()

for i in args.val.split('-'):
    print int(i) + 5
    sum += int(i) + 5
print 'the result is', sum
```

Now from command line type:

```
python foo_bar.py 230-20-5  > output.txt
```

You can try putting the code directly as well using:

```
python -c "import argparse;parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();parser.add_argument('val');args = parser.parse_args();for i in args.val.split('-'):print int(i) + 5;" 230-20-5 > output.txt
```

Although I could not get it to work!!!

Comment: thanks but I don't want to use a script , I want to do it from the command line